# What causes Firefox to make a GET request after submitting a form via the POST method?

Tags: firefox

What causes Firefox to follow a POST request with a GET request when submitting a form via the POST method? The GET method is sent to the same url as the POST method but without the request parameters.

If you change the form method to GET, it will result in two identical GET requests.

Comment: How are you determining there are extraneous GET requests? I'd like to see more specifics on the scenario. Can you post some excerpts of the HTML or specific web site examples?

Comment: A little question : have you set an onsubmit handler on your form tag ? Could you post the html/javascript source of your page ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Firefox 3. This happens when the response to the POST contains an image tag with an empty source attribute. eg `<img src=""/>`

Comment: Is this bug documented somewhere?

Comment: I found a similar bug in Firefox 39 today. If a submitted form contains a textarea and the text in the textarea contains `<img src="">` or even `<span src="">` that causes it to send a GET request to the form submit address (and happens also even if the src attribute is non-empty). The bug seemed to disappear after disabling all plugins but I couldn't verify it now. It could be caused by the Firebug plugin but this is only a guess.

Comment: @gregn3 After more digging it seems that the Noscript plugin was causing this behavior, and it is an anti-XSS feature that can be turned off...

Answer (score 2):

The URL POSTed to might be returning a Redirect -- that would cause a GET.  This is commonly done so that the page can be refreshed without reposting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some javascript involved. The form is submitted as a result of an onclick event in an anchor with:  href="..." onclick="..form.submit()"

Comment: I forgot to mention that this still occurs with JavaScript disabled.